# get_query_var('paged') for WP_Comment_Query always return 1 when using paginate_comments_links()

Tags: comments, pagination

I'm having a problem getting 'paged' query_var for my comments section in CPT post.

I'm using this code to query comments:

```
// Comments per page
$comments_per_page = get_option('comments_per_page');

// Paged variable
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

var_dump($paged); // This ALWAYS returns 1

$args = array(
    'status' => 'approve',
    'post_id' => $post->ID,
    'paged' => $paged,
    'number' => $comments_per_page,
);

// The comment Query
$comments_query = new WP_Comment_Query;
$comments = $comments_query->query( $args );
```

Then I call WordPress' core function to render pagination links

```
paginate_comments_links();
```

Everything seems to be working. When I change the `paged` argument inside the query manually to let's say 2, then the correct comments are fetched.
I'm sure the problem is in this line of code, since it ALWAYS return 1:

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
```

The URL looks like this when I click in the pagination `http://wordpress.test/diary-post/testing-diary-5/comment-page-2/`

The `/comment-page-{x})` is added by the pagination.

I've been already thinking of trying to extract the number from URL by parsing it, but that seems VERY WRONG. I'm pretty sure there is some part I'm blatantly missing

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: `get_query_var` is for the post query, not the comment query, even if you move to page 2 of the comments `paged` will still show `1` because the post only has one page. Is there a specific reason you're creating a brand new comment query instead of using the standardised comment system with custom templates? Are you aware of the `pre_get_comments` filter for changing the parameters without modifying the template?

Comment: Oh, I didn't really know about that, but now it makes sense. I'm creating brand new comment query just how it is specified in [codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/partial-and-miscellaneous-template-files/comment-template/) as first example. I could get it working within minutes very easily so I really liked the solution. 
I will look up the standarised comment system, looks like a way to go! 
Thanks for your answer.

Comment: just a comment, not an answer, I don't know the equivalent of `get_query_var` for comment queries so I didn't write an answer, but glad it helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm sure the problem is in this line of code, since it ALWAYS return
> 1:
>
> ```
> $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
> ```

Yes, that's correct.

And to retrieve the page number of the **current *comments page***, where the URL contains the `/comment-page-<number>`, use `get_query_var( 'cpage' )` and **not** `get_query_var( 'paged' )`, i.e. the query var name is `cpage` and **not** `paged`.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, thank you!